# Is there a general method or "good practice" to make requests.get run faster?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multithreading

The code of my test project keeps sending requests by bruteforce but runs slow after trying 40-50 requests. I'm not sure if it's the server that does something to halt the requests or the code is ineffiecient or both. I tried on multiple domains and it is slow there too.
Looking for good practices and ways to improve and learn when working other similar projects.

```
import requests

#the function bruteforces for subdomains through a file subdomain1k.txt.
#Tried sessions and setting a headers parameter which seems to have worked for some with requests

c = 0
def req(url):
    global c
    session = requests.Session()
    for _ in range(10):
        try:
            return session.get("https://" + url, headers = {'Connection': 'close'})
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            c+=1
            print("--------------")
            print(c)


#I was not sure if it was requests that was taking long or reading each line so set a buffer which did nothing to help with the speed
#the subdomain1k.txt contains 1000 subdomain prefixes like www, mail, ftp etc which it appends to target site for instance https://mail.google.com
#I was thinking if the subdomain1k.txt contained a million entries what the solution would be then?

target_url = "google.com"

with open('subdomain1k.txt', 'r', buffering=2<<16) as file:
    for line in file:
        word = line.strip()
        test_url = word + "." + target_url
        response = req(test_url)

        if response:
            print(test_url)
            # with open('out.txt', 'a') as write_text:
            #   write_text.write(test_url+"\n")
```

Comment: If you’re using a session you should use it for more than one request, i.e. don’t create a new session for every request. And when you get that working make sure to ditch the connection: close header because not closing the connection will speed up multiple requests to the same URL. OTOH if every URL is different then there’s nothing to gain from those changes.

Comment: @balmy not sure if I understood it correctly but I tried putting the session = session = requests.Session() outside the def req(url) function instead of inside the function, calling creating a new session for each time the function is used. I tried to change the forloop range from 10 to 5, 20 and 1 to see if it did anything different. I removed the header connection close parameter. It still halts and is slow unfortunately